# Reset tabBar.isHidden doesn't work in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The sequence is tabBarController->navigationController->viewController->viewController
I wrote the following code in the second viewController.
When the user comes to the second viewController, I want to hide the tab bar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

When the user clicks "Cancel" button, I want to go back to the main page.

```
@IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

After go back to the first viewController, I want to make the tab bar show again.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

But in fact, the tab doesn't show at all. And the page suddenly shakes for a moment. Don't know why.
[image: Workflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all your code for setting Tab bar, and try this option for Second View Controller in XIB or Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works. But why my code doesn't work as I expected?

Comment: Might be you forgot call: super.viewWillAppear(animated). if you forgot it could lead to very nasty issues to track down.